# Google Chrome App which opens a website?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

How can I make a Google Chrome App which will just open a website?

Like a shortcut for a website?

Comment: That seems pretty basic. Go read up on programming/whichever API is used for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty easy:

**`manifest.json`**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Test App",
    "description": "I'm a test app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "app": {
        "launch": {
            "web_url": "http://www.example.org/"  // This is the redirect URL
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "16.png",
        "48": "48.png",
        "128": "128.png"
    }
}
```

Just put `manifest.json`, `16.png`, `48.png` and `128.png` into a folder and your extension is complete.

After that, open up the **Extensions** page and check the **Developer Mode** checkbox. From there, you can bundle your extension or just install it unpacked by navigating to to the extension's folder:

[image]

Comment: Pretty answer for a basic question. It should be accepted.